# How to get stringstream to interpret char as an int without casting

Tags: c++

I have some code for converting an int to a string

```
char val = 0x79;

std::stringstream str1, str2;

str1 << std::hex << val;   
str2 << std::hex << (short) val;
std::cout << str1.str() << std::endl;
std::cout << str2.str() << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
y    
79
```

The second output is what I want but I don't like having to cast the char
to a short. Is there a way to get the output I want without the cast?

Comment: `+val`, if you like to do it that way.

Comment: This is about input. That was about output. I'm not sure the equivalent is clear enough to call them dupes.

Comment: I did find the information I wanted though. I did not know that stringstream has an overload for char so that it is interpreted as an ascii character instead of an int.